# pip cannot install websocket-server python packge

Tags: docker, centos, pip

I am inside my docker container, which is running centos6.6.1, and cannot seem to install the python package websocket-server.

```
pip install websocket-server

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement websocket-server (from versions: )
```

I managed to get around this issue with the following command:

```
pip install git+http://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server
```

but I don't like having to clone the repo in order to install the package. Any ideas how I can avoid this work around and get the first pip install to work?

I have the same problem with python package influxdb!

Answer (score 2):

First what You need to do inside docker is upgrade `pip` and `setuptools` packages:

```
pip install -U setuptools pip
```

Do it inside virtualenv (if You use it).